# Netbeans Radar Plugin Configuration

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 8.0.1 and I need to run and check SonarQube analysis from my IDE before commiting to SVN. I have installed the plugin Netbeans-Radar plugin for launch local analysis and check de results. This plugin has an option called "Get Issues With Sonnar Runner" for this purpose as I found in this web: http://code.google.com/p/radar-netbeans/

The problem is that when I run this option, after a moment, I recive a "Java Heap Space" error. I know what this error mean but I don't know how to solve it. I tried increasing the heap space of the Netbeans, adding the argument "-J-Xmx1024m" to the property "netbeans_default_options" in the file .../Netbeans 8.0/etc/netbeans.conf. The heap space of Netbeans is really increased, as I check with jvisualVM (the Netbeans process has 1GB heap space).

The problem is that the plugin launch an independent process and don't use the arguments indicated in the file netbeans.conf. In the error log, I see that this command is being launched:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin\java.exe -cp C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\sonar-runner-impl7326402756121541816.jar org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\sonar-project1505822727125430784.properties
```

So, the question is, can someone tell me how can I configure the Netbeans-Radar plugin in order to increase the heap space? How can I configure Netbeans or Radar plugin to use the argument "-Xmx1024m" when launching java.exe?

I use this versions: Netbeans 8.0.1, Radar-plugin 2.1

Comment: Feature requested at official site [http://code.google.com/p/radar-netbeans/issues/detail?id=29](http://code.google.com/p/radar-netbeans/issues/detail?id=29)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature was requested at official site in this link: http://code.google.com/p/radar-netbeans/issues/detail?id=29 and has been added in version 2.2-SNAPSHOT (not released at current date).

In the settings panel (tools > options > miscellaneous > SonarQube) there is an option called "Runner JVM arguments". I tried with 1GB (option -Xmx1024m) and now is working perfectly.