# SonarQube with Radar-Netbeans Plugin Exception

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, sonarqube

I am trying to analyze my code with radar-netbeans 2.4 plug-in on my 8.0.2 NetBeans IDE, at first my sonar-runner wasn't even executing, but after I read this post: "[Netbeans Radar Plugin Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839878/netbeans-radar-plugin-configuration)", I was able to get my sonar-runner to execute until I got this exception:

```
qubexplorer.runner.SonarRunnerException: No result file
at qubexplorer.runner.SonarRunnerProccess.executeRunner(SonarRunnerProccess.java:189)
at qubexplorer.ui.SonarRunnerTask.execute(SonarRunnerTask.java:95)
at qubexplorer.ui.SonarRunnerTask.execute(SonarRunnerTask.java:32)
at qubexplorer.ui.task.TaskExecutor$TaskWorker.doInBackground(TaskExecutor.java:62)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there something I can do to fix this exception? Keepin mind that the two are no longer compatible, but I don't really want to give up on this plug-in.

The details of my plug-in:

- Name:  radar-netbeans
- Version: 2.4
- Source: 1443318005_radar-netbeans-2.4.nbm
- Plugin Description: Sonar Plugin for Maven based projects.

I have had this plug-in work prior to installation of NetBeans 8.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue with :-

- SonarQube version : 5.2
- radar-netbeans version : 2.4
- Netbeans version : 8.1

Refer the Notes section :
https://github.com/hmvictor/radar-netbeans
'It works from SonarQube 3.7 to SonarQube 5.1.'

So, i changed to SonarQube 5.1 , and it works perfectly now, guess the plugin need to be promptly updated.

[sonarqube](/questions/tagged/sonarqube)[plugin](/questions/tagged/plugin)[netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans)

Comment: Trying to fix it turned out to be too time consuming, guess the plugin is just not good with newer version. I ended up using the console version.